# Internal k8s services communication not balanced

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, load-balancing, amazon-eks, kubernetes-networking

I’m running a k8s cluster on aws-eks.
I have two services A and B.

Service A listens to a rabbit queue and sends http request to service B (which takes a couple of seconds).
Both services scale based on the number of message in the queue.

The problem is that the requests from A to B are not balanced.
When scaled to about 100 pods each, I see that service A pods sends requests to only about 60% of service B pods at a given time,
Meaning, eventually all pods gets messages, but some pods are at 100 cpu receiving 5 messages at a time, while others at 2 cpu
Receiving 1 message every minute or so..
That obviously causes low performance and timeouts.

I’ve read that it should work in round robin, but when I tried to set 10 fixed replicas of each service (all pods already up and running)
And pushing 10 messages to queue, I’ve seen that all service A pods pulled a message to send to service B, but some of service B pods never got any requests while other got more than one - resulting in one whole process to finish within 4 second while another took about 12 second.

Any ideas for why it’s working like that and how to change it to be more balanced?

Thanks

Comment: not sure how valid this is ... but from your description, it sounds like a well-known issue when using iptables, while ipvs "should" be able to perform better distributing connections. In EKS, first result from google: https://medium.com/@selfieblue/how-to-enable-ipvs-mode-on-aws-eks-7159ec676965.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i've tried and it doesn't perform any better :(